# Storing List into Firestore In Multiple Map

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I wanted to store a List into Firestore.
I am working on a project and in this page I will need to select some selection (selection is the DocumentID) and store it in a `List`, After that I need to retrieve from the `List` and call Firestore again to get the `GeoPoint` of the item based on the `List` (the `List` contains the DocumentID). Then I am able to retrieve that as well thanks to the help of the community. But now I can only store one of the Item of the `List` and not all of them.

This is my code:

```
  void initRoute(data, dataInt) async{
    Firestore.instance.collection('routes').document(inputName).setData({
      dataInt:{
        "Lat" : data['location'].latitude,
        "Lng" : data['location'].longitude
      }
    });
  }
```

I am able to store but it only store the first Item in the List into the Firestore. How can i store all of them into just 1 Document with few `Map` something similar to the picture below.

And also the name of the `Map` can I generate it based on how many items I have in the list (1st item get 0, 2nd item get 1 and so on...)and add it in when storing? Thank you so much in advance.

[image]

**Edit:**
The `dataInt` is meant to do the numbering but I failed miserably but still do not know how to get it work.

**Update:**
I am getting all the `List` from Firestore.
Firstly the we select some from here:
[image: first]

Then the after selecting it will store the Name into the `List`

Code of using the `List`:

```
List<String> _selectedBusStop = List<String>();
```

Code of adding to `List` when `onTap` and `onLongPress`

```
onTap: (){
            if(_selectedBusStop.contains(user.data['BusstopName'])){
              setState(() {
                _selectedBusStop.removeWhere((val) => val == user.data['BusstopName']);
              });
            }
          },
          onLongPress: (){
              setState(() {
                _selectedBusStop.add(user.data['BusstopName']);
              });
          }
```

Because the List only have the `BusstopName` saved in it so I will need to read again from Firestore and get the `GeoPoint` that I needed. Saved it in a `Map` and use it as a `Polyline`. Now I am currently stuck at where I am unable to save all of the Item in the `List` into the Firestore when I am calling the `setData` as it only save 1 of the item in the `List` and I want to store all of it.

Sorry for causing misunderstanding again. Really sorry for that.

**Update** I am able to store all of the Item in my List into Firestore

```
  void initRoute(data, dataInt) async{
    Firestore.instance.collection('routes').document(inputName).setData({
      data['BusstopName']:{
        "Lat" : data['location'].latitude,
        "Lng" : data['location'].longitude
      }
    }, merge: true);
  }
```

with this code.

Answer (score 1):

First create a `Map` locally, give it the int you want:

```
Map<String,dynamic> dataToBeSent ={ 
       '0': {
        "Lat" : data['location'].latitude,
        "Lng" : data['location'].longitude}
        }
```

Now, before sending to firebase, you know if this is the first LatLng or not, if it's the first, you use `.set`, like this:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('routes').document(inputName).setData(dataToBeSent);
```

This will create a new document, with the coordinates inside a `Map` and it has the index you want. Later on, you want to add another LatLng to this document, you use `.update`, and send the new `Map`.

```
Map<String,dynamic> dataToBeSent2 ={ 
       '2': {
        "Lat" : data['location'].latitude,
        "Lng" : data['location'].longitude}
        }

Firestore.instance.collection('routes').document(inputName).updateData(dataToBeSent2);
```

This will keep updating the keys you are sending, but be careful to not store a new map using the same id, for example `0`, it will over write what is currently at key `0` in firebase.

---

Based on your edits and comment replies, first start with this:

```
  void initRoute(data, dataInt) async{
    if(data.isNotEmpty){
      for(int a = 0; a < data; a++){
        Map<String,dynamic> dataToBeSent={
          $a:{
            "Lat" : data['location'].latitude,
            "Lng" : data['location'].longitude
          }
        };
        Firestore.instance.collection('routes').document(inputName).setData(dataToBeSent);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi good sir. I know its you again hahaha. I wanted to save all of the Item in the `List` all together. So like the `0` will be able to update himself. So like my `List` have 3 item, the first Item will have the `Map` named 0 and it's own `LatLng`, the second item will have the `Map` named 1 and it's own `LatLng` as well. The 3rd item in the `List` will have named as 2 and it's own `LatLng`. Maybe something like `i++` is it going to work cause i tried it said that they need `String` to be able to save it.

Comment: That'll work, whenever you need to update any index, just use `.updateData{'$i':{'Lat':...etc}}

Comment: Just convert the index from `i++` to a string when you use it as a key.

Comment: Sir I think there is a misunderstanding. I don't want to update but when `SetData` I want all of the item in the List to be stored directly into the Firestore.

Comment: You need to convert your list locally first into a map, then send it to firebase. Please share an example of your list of polygons, and we'll convert it

Comment: I updated my question. But im not sure do i provide enough information for you to help me in this.

Comment: And also the i dont undertsand the part where convert index from `i++` can you show me a simple example?

Comment: thankyou for being so so patient with me. I really is in a mess...

Comment: It's okay, I edited my answer, check it now. But this will only add one item I assume. First, get it to add one item, then we can create more items.

Comment: It gives me error saying its an undefined name for `$a`

Comment: try `a.toString()` instead of `$a`.

Comment: Nothing has been saved. It shows this error
`Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'num'` but for `a.toString()` does not show error