# Saving Item from List to Firestore with the same Sequence of List

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I have a `List` with a specific sequence that I need to follow to be able get the Polyline to work properly. From my understanding, when saving into Firestore it will re-order all them item I have in ascending order.

Example of List:
`List _selectedBusStop = ['Mahsuri', 'Imperial', 'Garden']`

Saved into Firestore(it will change the sequence):
`['Garden', 'Imperial', 'Mahsuri']`
as in ascending order

Can I somehow save the item exactly the same as the `Example List`?

This is the code that I am using

```
List<String> _selectedBusStop = List<String>();

    Future <void> saveRoute() async{
        Firestore.instance.collection('markers').where('BusstopName', whereIn: _selectedBusStop)
            .snapshots().listen((location) {
          if(location.documents.isNotEmpty){
            for (int i = 0; i < location.documents.length; i++){
              initRoute(location.documents[i].data, location.documents[i]);
            }
          }
        });
        setState(() {
        });

  }

void initRoute(data, dataInt) async{
   Firestore.instance.collection('routes').document(inputName).setData({
      data['BusstopName']:{
        "Lat" : data['location'].latitude,
        "Lng" : data['location'].longitude
      }
    }, merge: true);
  }
```

If I print `_selectedBusStop` and `data` the sequence is different. How can I make it the same sequence?
[image: sequence]

Comment: Once again, please share the actual list you have of item2,3,1 and exactly how you want it to be posted, and how you want them to be fetched, it'll be easier to get a direct answer. It might be easier for an answerer to give a method different than the one you are using currently, and could likely be better off for you, instead of having to mutate the answer to work with your functions' logic like `saveRoute` and `initRoute`.  Write the list as they are. `List stops = ['Mahsuri', 'Garden']` and `List markers = [3.4425,5.33345]` for example.

Comment: The picture have the List that I am saying in this case. `List _selectedBusStop = ['Mahsuri', 'Imperial', 'Garden']`

Answer (score 1):

The reason you retrieve the documents in a different order is that Firestore returns the documents in ascending order by document ID when you don't specify an order. You can find the details in the docs:

### [Order and limit data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data)

> By default, a query retrieves all documents that satisfy the query in
> ascending order by document ID.

So, you should instead use `orderBy()` to get the documents in the order you want.

### [orderBy](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/orderBy.html)

> Creates and returns a new Query that's additionally sorted by the
> specified field. The field may be a String representing a single field
> name or a FieldPath.

Provide a unique number for each bus stop name in ascending order (1, 2, 3 ...). Store those numbers in a field named `busStopId` in each document. Then, get the documents in ascending order by `busStopId`:

```dart
Firestore.instance.collection('routes').orderBy('busStopId').get().then(
    (QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach(
        (doc) {
          print(doc);
        },
      );
    },
  );
```

Comment: but how can I `orderBy` using the `List` that i have as reference. I tried something like this `.orderBy('BusstopName' == _selectedBusStop)` but it is not working

Comment: First, you need to clarify how you set order for `_selectedBusStop`. Do you manually order the list? Or, it's based on a logic? If you decide the order manually, provide a number for each bus stop like 1, 2, 3... that you can use to order documents. Second, this is not how you use `orderBy()`. Take a look at the FlutterFIre docs: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#ordering

Comment: Ya I am manually adding them into the `List` so if I am able to give them the numbers then I `orderBy()` the number?

Comment: Sorry for being misleading. I don't think this can solve the issue I have for this case. The reason is that I have Data of the Bus Station all in Firestore and even if I gave them their numbers it is still can't accomplish. I am making a route and its is based on the Bus Station I have in the Firestore and the sequence will wary depends on the User's selection so sometimes it will be [2,7,4] sometimes it will be [3,5,1] and the `List` that I mention here is based on the selection of the User it will change everytime the user update. So is there no way for it to follow the order in the `List`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68835112/storing-list-into-firestore-in-multiple-map 
In this link will be able to understand the case that I am currently in. Sorry that I didn't explain throughoutly.

Comment: I see. I don't think there is a way to sort Firestore documents by a dynamic list of items. You could still sort locally using Dart, though.